Find the number of pairs of two consecutive zeros
the problem
We call a binary sequence of length $n$ a string with $n$ digits of $0$ or $1$. For such a sequence, $A$,
of finite length,$f(A)$ represents a transformation where every 1 in $A$ becomes $0,1$ and every $0$
of $A$ becomes $1,0$. e.g $f((1,0,1))=(0,1,1,0,0,1)$  Find the number of pairs of two
consecutive zeros from $f^{(n)}((1))$, where $f^{(n)}((A))$ is the sequence obtained by transforming $A$ $n$ times.
my idea
I think first of all we should try some values for $n$ and try finding a rule



value of n
how A looks like




0
1


1
0,1


2
1,0,0,1


3
0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1


4
1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1



As we can see I think if we have a zero and a one consecutivly we can make a pair of 3 consecutive zero. Although this pair will be destroyed next transformation.
I don't know what to do forward! Hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

This is a minor point but would eventually affect calculations: if $n$ is the length of the string, to $n=0$ corresponds the empty string, so it should be $n \gt 0$, while the question should really ask about $f^{(k)}$ for $k\ge 0$, where $k$ is the number of applications of $f$ to any given string.  --  That said, here is just an idea: (IIANM, should be proved) given a string, say $s$, the string $f(s)$ is equal to the string obtained by concatenating $\neg s$ with $s$, where $\neg$ is bitwise negation.

You use variable $n$ two times. First, when you define a binary string. Second, when you denote the number of transformations of a string. This causes misunderstanding.

Here’s another approach, somewhat more head-on than Aig’s nice answer: I’ll start by working out how $f$ and its iterates act on occurrences of 00 in general, before looking at your specific starting value for the iteration.
Let’s write $\newcommand{\occ}[2]{\mathrm{occ}_{#1}({#2})} \occ{b}{a}$ for the number of occurrences of a string $b$ as a substring of $a$ — so in this notation, your problem asks for $\occ{00}{f^n(1)}$.  And write $l(a)$ for the length of a string $a$.
Now for any string $a$, what is $\occ{00}{f(a)}$?  Occurrences of $00$ in $f(a)$ will come exactly from occurrences of $01$ in $a$ (which become $1001$ in $f(a)$) — that is,
$$\occ{00}{f(a)} = \occ{01}{a}.$$
Now start to iterate: what about $\occ{00}{f^2(a)}$?  Using the preceding equation, $\occ{00}{f^2(a)} = \occ{00}{f(f(a))} = \occ{01}{f(a)}$.  But occurrences of $01$ in $f(a)$ can arise in two ways: from occurrences of $1$ in $a$, and occurrences of $00$.  So we get:
$$\occ{00}{f^2(a)} = \occ{01}{f(a)} = \occ{00}{a} + \occ{1}{a}.$$
This formula with $f^2$ looks much better for further iteration: it expresses $\occ{00}{f^2(a)}$ just in terms of $\occ{00}{a}$ itself, together with $\occ{1}{a}$, whose behaviour under iteration is very simple since $\occ{1}{f(a)} = l(a)$, and so $\occ{1}{f^n(a)} = 2^{n-1}l(a)$ for $n>0$.
So for any even iterate $f^{2n}(a)$, we can repeatedly expand using the formula for $\occ{00}{f^2(a)}$ as follows:
$$\begin{aligned}
\occ{00}{f^{2n}(a)} &= \occ{00}{f^2(f^{2n-2}(a))} \\
  & = \occ{00}{f^{2n-2}(a)} + \occ{1}{f^{2n-2}(a)} \\
  & = \occ{00}{f^{2n-2}(a)} + 2^{2n-3}l(a) \\
  & = \occ{00}{f^{2n-4}(a)} + 2^{2n-5}l(a) + 2^{2n-3}l(a)\\
  & \ \ \vdots \\
  & = \occ{00}{a} + \occ{1}{a} + 2l(a) + \cdots + 2^{2n-5}l(a) + 2^{2n-3}l(a) \\
  & = \occ{00}{a} + \occ{1}{a} + 2l(a)\sum_{i=0}^{n-2} 2^{2i} \\
  & = \occ{00}{a} + \occ{1}{a} + 2l(a)\frac{4^{n-1}-1}{3}. \\
\end{aligned}$$
Looking over this more carefully, we get the overall formula
$$ \occ{00}{f^{2n}(a)} = \occ{00}{a} + \occ{1}{a} + 2l(a)\frac{4^{n-1}-1}{3}$$
and can check it holds for all $n > 1$ (formally, this can be proved by induction).  From this we can get a similar formula for the odd iterates:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\occ{00}{f^{2n+1}(a)} &= \occ{00}{f^{2n}(f(a))} \\
& =  \occ{01}{f(a)} + \occ{1}{f(a)} + 2l(f(a))\frac{4^{n-1}-1}{3} \\
& =  \occ{01}{a} + l(a) + 4l(a)\frac{4^{n-1}-1}{3} \\
& =  \occ{01}{a} + l(a)\frac{4^n-1}{3}. \\
\end{aligned} $$
Putting it all together, we have formulas for $\occ{00}{f^n(a)}$ for all $n \geq 0$, in terms of $\occ{00}{a}$, $\occ{01}{a}$, $\occ{1}{a}$, and $l(a)$:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\occ{00}{f^0(a)} &= \occ{00}{f(a)} \\
\occ{00}{f^{2n+1}(a)} & = \occ{01}{a} + l(a)\frac{4^n-1}{3} & (n \geq 0)\\
\occ{00}{f^{2n}(a)} &= \occ{00}{a} + \occ{1}{a} + 2l(a)\frac{4^{n-1}-1}{3} & (n>0).\\
\end{aligned}$$
Now for your specific case we set $a=1$, and get:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\occ{00}{f^0(1)} &= 0 \\
\occ{00}{f^{2n+1}(1)} & = \frac{4^n-1}{3} & (n \geq 0)\\
\occ{00}{f^{2n}(1)} &= 1 + 2\frac{4^{n-1}-1}{3} & (n>0).\\
\end{aligned} $$
It would be perfectly reasonable to stop here; but one might also notice that the latter two cases look quite similar, and susspect that they can be unified. To do so, rewrite the powers of 4 into powers of 2 and simplify slightly:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\occ{00}{f^{2n+1}(1)} & = \frac{2^{2n}-1}{3} = \frac{2^{(2n+1)-1}-1}{3} & (n \geq 0)\\
\occ{00}{f^{2n}(1)} &= 1 + 2\frac{2^{2n-2}-1}{3} = \frac{2^{2n-1}+1}{3} & (n>0)\\
\end{aligned} $$
and then note that these can both be rewritten as:
$$\boxed{\occ{00}{f^{k}(1)} = \frac{2^{k-1}+(-1)^k}{3}} \qquad (k>0).$$

Interesting approach! I, first, found the recurrent relations between $\text{occ}{00}$, $\text{occ}{01}$, $\text{occ}{10}$, $\text{occ}{10}$, using your terms. But wasn’t able to “solve” them. I guess, the key was to include $\text{occ}{0}$, $\text{occ}{1}$!

Here is a full solution. First of all, note that your sequence of strings is very similar to the Thue-Morse sequence. The only difference is that, if $n$ is even, a string in your sequence is inverted ($0$s become $1$s, and vice versa). Similar to the Thue-Morse sequence, your sequence can be constructed in a similar way. To get a $n+1$-st string one should take an $n$-th string and add an inverted $n$-th string to the beginning of it.
We will prove that by induction. The first string transformation $1\to01$ respects this rule. Consider a string $\overline ss$, which was transformed from $s$. (We denote a string where $1$s are substituted by $0$s and vice versa by $\overline s$.) What will happen next? The right half of $\overline ss$, which is $s$, will becomes $\overline ss$, as we already know. The left half $\overline s$ is inverted $s$, and since the rules $0\to 10$ and $1\to 01$ are inversions of each other, $\overline s$ will become $s\overline s$. Hence, $\overline ss$ will become $s\overline s\overline ss$, just as we wanted to prove.
This means that all substrings $00$ are preserved when go to the next string, also all $11$s become $00$s in the first half of the new string, too. And there can be one more $00$ in the place of concatenation. It is easy to see, that for even $n$ a string begins and ends in $1$. And for odd $n$ a string begins by $0$ and ends by $1$. So there appears one more $00$ when we go from an odd string to the next one.
Let us denote the number of $00$s in the $n$-th string by $a_n$, the number of $11$s in the $n$-th string by $b_n$ ($n$ is the number of a string as in the OP’s table, or the number of transformations). Then the following is true (for $n\ge0$):
$$\begin{align} a_{n+1}&=a_n+b_n+e_n\\
b_{n+1}&=a_n+b_n,\end{align}$$
where $e_n$ is $1$ if $n$ is odd, and $0$ otherwise. In other words, $e_n=\frac12+\frac12(-1)^{n-1}$. One can see that the following is true for $a_n$, $b_n$ (for $n\gt0$):
$$\begin{align} a_{n+1}&=2a_n+(-1)^{n+1}\\
b_{n+1}&=2b_n+1-e_n.\end{align}$$
Indeed, we have $$a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n+e_n=a_n+(a_n-e_{n-1})+e_n=$$ $$=2a_n-\frac12-\frac12(-1)^{n-2}+\frac12+\frac12(-1)^{n-1}=2a_n+(-1)^{n-1}.$$
The second equation is not really needed for our goal. But we can see, that $$b_{n+1}=a_n+b_n=(b_n+e_{n-1})+b_n=2b_n+1-e_n.$$
Now we just have to “solve” the recursion for $a_n$. If the equation were homogeneous, then the solution would be $a_n=k\cdot2^n$. The particular solution of the non-homogeneous equation has a form $l\cdot(-1)^n$. Putting this into the equation we get $$l\cdot(-1)^{n+1}=2l\cdot(-1)^n+(-1)^{n+1}.$$
Dividing by $(-1)^n$ we get $l\cdot(-1)=2l+(-1)$, so $l=\frac13$. Hence $a_n=k\cdot 2^n+\frac{(-1)^n}3$ for some $k$. Knowing that $a_1=0$ we find: $$0=k\cdot2-\frac13.$$
So, $k=\frac16$. And finally, for $n\gt0$: $$\boxed{a_n=\frac{2^{n-1}+(-1)^n}3.}$$
Out of curiosity, we can find $b_n$:
$$b_n=a_{n}-e_{n-1}=\frac{2^{n-1}+(-1)^n}3-\frac12-\frac12(-1)^{n}=$$
$$=\frac{2^{n-1}-\frac32-\frac12(-1)^n}3.$$

The approach looks fine, but it's not clear to me if $a_n$ here refers to the $n-$th iteration of the transformation, or the length. It seems you fail to take into account that we start with an arbitrary $n-$ length string, and we apply the iteration exactly $n$ times (otherwise the result should be undetermined)

@leonbloy $n$ is the number of string as in the OP’s table. We start from the one-digit string $1$, as claimed in the OP’s post. We want to find $f^{(n)}(1)$.

@leonbloy I guess, your confusion comes from the fact that OP uses the same variable $n$ twice, causing conflict. First, when defining a binary string. Second, when denoting the number of transformations.

Yes, my bad, thanks
